# Design the database of tasks that are heavily dependent on each of them

Tags: database-design

I have no idea how to structure this use case... Basically the requirement is that we want to handle tasks.

Let's say we have a class `Task` with the following fields and functions:

- `PlannedStartDate` of type `DateTime`
- `PlannedEndDate` of type `DateTime`
- `PlannedEffortInSeconds` of type `Integer`
- `GetPlannedDurationInSeconds()` that returns an `Integer` that is `PlannedEndDate - PlannedStartDate`.

A task can be divided into (sub)tasks. With this, we can create a tree of tasks since every tasks can be divided into more tasks. Therefore we have new fields and functions to add to the class:

- `Children` of type `List<Task>`
- `GetExpectedEffortInSeconds()` which returns the sum of the `GetExpectedEffortInSeconds()` of the children if the task have children, and if not it returns its `PlannedEffortInSeconds`.
- `GetExpectedStartDate()` which returns the smallest `GetExpectedStartDate()` of the children if it has, and if not it returns its `PlannedStartDate`
- `GetExpectedEndDate()` which returns the greatest `GetExpectedEndDate()` of the children if it has, and if not it returns its `PlannedEndDate`
- `GetExpectedDuration()` which returns `GetExpectedEndDate() - GetExpectedStartDate()`

Additionally, a task can have dependencies, making a task dependent of another task. This forces the `GetExpectedStartDate()` function to returns a value equal or greater than the `GetExpectedEndDate()` of the dependency task. With this, we have new fields and functions:

- `Dependencies` of type `List<Task>`

I'm having trouble to understand how I could handle this in server when there are thousands of tasks.
I thought about lazy loading children and dependencies, which allow me to display a task and its cached data without loading everything, but If we update a task that is a parent of a lot of tasks and a predecessors of more tasks then it takes several seconds to update everything since it is done recursively and with lazy loading it takes more time to load (since we don't know when to stop, so we either load everything - 10 000 tasks - or we fetch until there is nothing to update).

Comment: What's wrong with loading everything? As long as your objects are individually handcrafted task descriptions, you'll never be able to fill up the RAM of any machine sold in the last years. Paging is for multi-million-record situations.

Comment: @KilianFoth I had issues with this because it takes too much to update the tasks. But maybe the problem is not loading...

Comment: *If we update a task that is a parent of a lot of tasks and a predecessors of more tasks then it takes several seconds to update everything* I am not clear on why updating a task requires a cascading update of all its subtasks. Can you explain what you are thinking?